# How are attributes spread in each specific class?

Tags: diablo-iii

Every class gets a certain amount of points per level up. How are these points distributed in each of the five classes?

Comment: Does it matter? It's not something you can alter.

Comment: @RavenDreamer If I'm not mistaken, each attribute effects each class differently so it might be nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute gain is 5 points  per level, and they are mostly distributed in favor of your main attribute.

For example: Monk will gain at 2-3 dexterity, and the remaining points are distributed to the other stats (all stats won't necessarily increase, either).

The remaining stats may get a 1-2 point upgrade; I've been noticing a pattern where as a monk, I usually get 2-3 dex, 1-2 vitality, 0-1 int, 0-1 str.

So it would seem there's the main preferred stat, a secondary stat, and leftovers. :P

Quote from Game Director of D3, Jay Wilson:

> Stat progression as a system is very difficult for a lot of players to
>   understand because you get these 5 points, but you don’t exactly know
>   where to put them or what benefit you’re getting with them. You might
>   make some obvious choices, for example, with Diablo II’s Sorceress,
>   you might put all of your points into energy because that’s the
>   obvious choice, right? Except that for almost every build out there,
>   you’ve just made the wrong choice. Any system where you have to go up
>   onto the Internet to figure out what the right answer is, is not a
>   good customization system. Any system where there’s a “right” answer
>   is not a good system for customization. The truth is, with stat point
>   systems, they are simple math. It’s not hard to figure out what the
>   absolute best choice is so we decided we didn’t want that as a
>   customization system.
>
> With that being said, we do have another system we’re working on. The
>   specific intent of it is to capture the imagination of what stat point
>   spending was supposed to do, which is, “I want to be stronger. I want
>   to be tougher.” These kind of simple ideas are not contextualized well
>   within a skill system. The skill system is about what the player is
>   doing, not higher ideals about what their character is. So, we’re
>   going to work on a system that really satisfies that feeling, but is
>   way easier to understand and also has some true customization to it.

Comment: Is there a set way it is distributed every level or does it change each level?

Comment: Changing around each lvl up, probably some pre-set pattern tho.