# What are the primary stats for each Champion?

Tags: diablo-iii

- **Witch Doctor**: ?
- **Barbarian**: ?
- **Wizard**: ?
- **Monk**: Dexterity
- **Demon Hunter**: ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are attributes spread in each specific class?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67400/how-are-attributes-spread-in-each-specific-class)

Comment: The reason they downvoted is probably because the tooltip of the stats say for which class it is important. So they probably think you're question shouldn't have been asked, because I don't see how you could improve it other than stating some of your own findings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary stat is the stat that modifies damage by 1% per point -

- **Intelligence** is the primary stat for **Witch Doctors** and **Wizards**
- **Dexterity** is the primary stat for **Monks** and **Demon Hunters**
- **Strength** is the primary stat for **Barbarians**.